# Toshiba- battery won't quit charging

Tags: laptop, battery

Toshiba laptop with Windows 10. Battery charges to 94% but will not quit charging and won't go any higher. 
What do I do?
My problem has been solved. Thanks.

Comment: Additional information from you would likely improve the responses to your question such as: Age of the laptop, model, battery type/aftermarket, and other details about your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. I decided to first try what LP Chip suggested. My problem is solved. Next time I'll try to remember to add the additional info from the getgo.

Answer (score 2):

Your battery isn't calibrated anymore. It actually reaches 100% but because it isn't calibrated, it keeps charging, which damages the battery.

Luckily there is a trick you can do for any kind of rechargeable battery (also works for phones).

First, Use up the battery until the laptop turns off. Keep in mind, that it will at some point put the laptop in stand-by to save power. Given that you don't actually want that, at some point when it starts doing this, reboot the laptop and enter the bios so you can keep it on.

Do anything you can do to make the battery drain faster, such as enable bluetooth, put the brightness on highest, and perhaps play some games.

At some point when the battery is near its lowest point, it may turn off the laptop. Without charging, turn the laptop on as many times as you can until it really does not turn on anymore. In odd cases, this can be up to 100 times, so be prepared for that.

When the laptop finally won't turn on anymore, put the charger on and charge it up all the way to 100%. Don't unplug early, make sure you charge up to 100% in one go. You can use the laptop while doing so, but it will make charging take longer. So it is probably better to keep it charging while powered off for an hour before turning it on.

Once the battery is at 100% and you're sure it isn't charging anymore (the icon will change) you can unplug the power, and your battery is calibrated.

Alternatively but definitely not required, you can of course buy a new battery.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I didn't enter the bios but I did let the battery drain as completely as possible without that extra step and it worked! Put it on full brightness and turned the battery saver as low as possible(5 %) and it drained completely with no rebooting necessary.I have a 2014 Toshiba with Windows 10 on it. Much appreciate your help.

Comment: @NatalkaAnna : Feel free to mark this answer as answered then, so others know you no longer need any help.